# Cannot run the react-native project

Tags: react-native, gradle

I bought a new laptop and set up the environment variables and everything. And I created a normal react-native project and when I try to run it I am getting this message.

"   Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat tasks FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong: Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\USER\Downloads\project_2\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\USER.gradle\caches\8.0.1\scripts\4irw9eneszvh0x724tfyer3i2). > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 64 * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get
  the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 3m 22s
  Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.1-all.zip ...............10%................20%................30%................40%................50%................60%................70%................80%................90%................100% Welcome to Gradle 8.0.1! Here are the highlights of this release: - Improvements to the Kotlin DSL - Fine-grained parallelism from the first build with configuration cache - Configurable Gradle user home cache cleanup For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/release-notes.html Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster).   "

Does anyone know the solution for this problem?  (This is not the gradlew.bat installdebug issue )

Comment: Check your settings.gradle file

Comment: There is no issue in the setting.gradle file.   " rootProject.name = 'Resturant_App_1'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin')   "

Comment: if (settings.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && settings.newArchEnabled == "true") {
    include(":ReactAndroid")
    project(":ReactAndroid").projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid')
    include(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine")
    project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine").projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/hermes-engine')
}